# Is it wise to "nest" UIViewControllers inside other UIViewControllers like you would UIViews?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've got a fairly complex view, for me anyway, that has a few "trays" with custom interface items on them. They slide in and out of my root view. I'd like to nest (addSubview) the items inside the view. Each needs some setup before being displayed...and none can be configured in IB (they're subclasses of UIView).

I'm wondering if it makes sense to subclass UIViewController for each "tray" and then have the VC's view property point to the "tray" view which I can populate with my custom UIView objects. This way I can leverage the viewDidLoad, etc... methods in UIViewController.

I'm not aware of others doing this - at least in the few samples I've looked at. It would create a situation where there would be multiple view controllers being displayed on the screen at once. from the Navigation controller itself on down to the rootViewController and its view and then any number (well, screen size permitting) of these small trayViewControllers.  If so, how's the responder chain work? i assume it'd go from lowest UIView to its enclosing VC, then to that VC's parent view, then that view's VC, etc. etc. repeat, repeat.. up to UIApplication... am I asking for trouble?

OR, do I just stick with UIViews and adding subviews into subviews, etc. etc..

Comment: This is *exactly* what I am trying to do, so if you do it please post some more details!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Prior to iOS 5.0 this will specifically not recommended because the nested view controllers' lifecycle events – viewWillAppear, etc. – won't be called. See [Abusing UIViewControllers](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/).

> With multiple UIViewController’s views visible at once some of those controllers may not receive important messages like -viewWillAppear: or -didReceiveMemoryWarning. Additionally some of their properties like parentViewController and interfaceOrientation may not be set or updated as expected.

iOS 5.0 added [containment UIViewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW86) that correctly handles those lifecycle events by adding child view controllers.

```
- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController
```

I spent countless hours trying to get nested view controllers to work in iOS 4. I eventually did, but it required a lot of glue code that was easy to get wrong. Then I saw the warning in the docs.

Comment: use following link  for how to add child view in viewController http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151026/unable-to-programatically-create-a-uiviewcontroller-in-swift/35888118#35888118

Answer (score 7):

I'm trying to do the same thing, but was dissuaded from your approach by Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which states that *"You should not use view controllers to manage views that fill only a part of their window—that is, only part of the area defined by the application content rectangle. If you want to have an interface composed of several smaller views, embed them all in a single root view and manage that view with your view controller."*

Comment: I believe that assumes composition—that is, all of the "smaller views" are on-screen at once. I don't think it considers subviews that swap in and out.

Comment: In other words, "One ViewController per screen of your app".

Comment: It's easy enough to say "one CV per screen" and all, but you don't always want all your code for all subviews in the same CV. At least not if more than one view needs complex logic and could (potentially) be used in other view hierarchies.

Answer (score 1):

My experience on what you are trying to do has been a good one. I try to keep nib files as simple as possible, so I take any posible "subview" and encapsulate it in its own nib file with it's own view controller, therefore I end up having nested view controllers.
In one of my apps I have a very complex table view cell, that has a subview. So I ended up having a hierarchy that goes like this: the tableview controller on the top level, the tableviewcell's controllers for each row and inside each of these a subviewcontroller for the subview inside each cell.

And everything works fine.

Pardon my english.

Comment: just define viewcontroller instances inside other viewcontrollers

Comment: Nesting view controllers without using the new container view controller methods (or manually calling lifecycle methods) will cause bugs