# How can I create a interface (UIView) in a different class and add on my screen

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uiview

I want to create a different class with a view and call that class on screen.
When I run the app, the view does not appear. If I delete that structure and create the button on the main file, it works fine. When I put it on a different class, it does not work.

MyView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface viewHome : UIViewController

-(UIView*) myHome;

@end
```

MyView.m (Creating a button for test)

```
#import "viewHome.h"

@implementation viewHome

-(UIView*) myHome {
    UIView * myScreen = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    myScreen.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIButton * myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,100,44);
    [myButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [myScreen addSubview:myButton];

    return myScreen;
}
@end
```

viewController.m
[...]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    viewHome * fncScreen;
    UIView * homeScreen = [fncScreen myHome];
    [self.view addSubview:homeScreen];

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad practice to add one viewController's view as a subview to an another viewcontroller. (unless you are using certain classes/methods that let you have childViewControllers).

Its exactly for this reason, your view doesn't appear in one case, and appears in the other case.

try adding the `-(UIView*) myHome` method in your viewController.m, and do a

```
 [self.view addsubview: [self myHome]];
```

here's a good SO post about Nested UIViewControllers:

[Is it wise to "nest" UIViewControllers inside other UIViewControllers like you would UIViews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141015/is-it-wise-to-nest-uiviewcontrollers-inside-other-uiviewcontrollers-like-you-w)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious mistake I see in your code is this line:

```
viewHome * fncScreen;
```

OK, that's a pointer declaration, but you didn't actually create the object.
You need something like this:

```
viewHome * fncScreen = [[viewHome alloc] init];
```

Then you can call methods on such initialized object.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the method [fncScreen myHome] after allocation your view homeScreen.
like this -

```
UIView *homeScreen = [[UIView alloc] init];
homeScreen = [funScreen myHome];
[self.view addSubView: homeScreen];
[homeScreen release];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That's the same I wrote :) btw, he probably will not need the last line of your code snippet, in fact it will even throw an error. ARC is the default option for the last 2 years!